# Not receiving data for google analytics for android app

Tags: android, google-analytics, adb

I am trying to give my android application support of google analytics. Google analytics is giving me real-time data for my application, If I install my application on mobile using adb installer. However, If I am installing my application on mobile using signed apk by package installer, I am not getting report in google analytics.

How can I make google analytics work for android application installed via package installer.

Please note :- I have yet not uploaded my apk to play store.

Comment: Can you explain more, When it work and when it do not work?

Comment: Google analytics is not working for both, debug and release APK. It is only working when I am installing using adb command (Via eclipse, Run As -> Android Application).

Comment: In same phone/device?

Comment: Yes, In same phone. I am email generated APK, and installing from there.

Comment: adb command install phone and email install phone is same ? i ask you this think..

Comment: Yes, Both are same phone.

Comment: Check your logcat , it show message if it give error or not, after install via email. I think, it help to find error.  Because sometime real-time depended on network that are use for internet.

Comment: You were right. During package installation, logcat showed me following error  :-
E/GAV3(2750): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Error on GAThread: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.execute
E/GAV3(2750):  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ap.a(Unknown Source)
E/GAV3(2750):  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ak.a(Unknown Source)
E/GAV3(2750):  at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.s.g(Unknown Source)
E/GAV3(2750): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Google Analytics is shutting down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sebastien and @Md Abdul Gafur, I am finally able to solve the problem.
The problem of due to proguard. On looking Logcat of application, after installation via package installer, I saw following error :

01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Error on GAThread: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.client.HttpClient.execute
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ap.a(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ak.a(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.s.g(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.s.f(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.s.a(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.u.run(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750):   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.ab.run(Unknown Source)
01-01 13:55:22.703: E/GAV3(2750): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Google Analytics is shutting down.

I still don't know what line to add in proguard to solve this error. So I decided to disable proguard. Disabling the proguard solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The below statement solved the problem for me. Add it to your proguard.cfg or proguard-rules.pro file.

```
-keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is certainly due to a difference in the way of building your APK for debug and release mode (signed APK).

Do you use Proguard?

If so, do not forget to add

```
-keep public class com.google.** {*;}
```

to your proguard.cfg

Comment: Yes, I am using proguard. However, adding above mentioned line in progaurd didn't solved the problem. 
Google analytics is not working for both, debug and release APK. It is only working when I am installing using adb command (Via eclipse).